# Push array into array with keys

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am currently working with arrays and pushing items into an array. Below I have for loop, inside CasperJS is invoked and links are scrapped and placed in array. Page links are placed in array named `page_links` and video links in array `video_links`. However I am trying to merge both arrays into one array. How can I push the items in array with keys?

```
var page_links = [];
var video_links = [];

for (var i = 0; i < categoryUrls.length; i++)
{ // start for loop
    casper.thenOpen(categoryUrls[i], function() {
        tryAndScroll(this);
        casper.then(function() {
          this.getElementsInfo('.title').forEach(function(element) {
            // skip elements that don't have a href attribute...
            if (!element.attributes.href) {
              return;
            }
            page_links.push( element.attributes.href );
            casper.thenOpen(element.attributes.href, function() {
              this.click('.responsivewrapper');
            }).then(function(){
              casper.each(this.getElementsInfo('.badge-youtube-player'), function(casper, element, j) {
                video_links.push( element["attributes"]["src"] );
              });
            });
          });
        });
    });
}
```

Desired result

```
{ { 'page_link' : 'www.example.com', 'video_link' : 'www.example.com' }, {  'page_link' : 'www.example.com', 'video_link' : 'www.example.com' } }
```

Comment: Can we please have jsfiddle.net for that?

Comment: Does the first array has all `page_link` and the other `video_link`?

Comment: @BikasVaibhav yes correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the arrays as, which you can obtain by any means which I'm not considering here -

```
var page_links = [ "Link1", "link2" ];
var video_links = [ "vlink1", "vlink2" ];
```

Also assuming length of both arrays are same (you can apply logic to check this, which I've omitted here), here is the solutions

```
var finalArr = [];
for(var ii = 0, ll = page_links.length; ii < ll; ii++) {
    finalArr[ii] = {};
    finalArr[ii].page_link = page_links[ii];
    finalArr[ii].video_link = video_links[ii];
}
```

Thie `finalArr` will be updated with following array details

```
[{page_link: "Link1", video_link: "vlink1"}, ...];
```

Comment: This code should be run *after* all the URLs are scraped. If OP wants it integrated a Closure must be used to fix `ii`.